# Closure of the set $\{1 \} $ in $ \tau_{1} \cap \tau_{2} $

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\tau_{1} $ and $ \tau_{2} $ be two topologies on $X = \Bbb R$ defined as:

$ \tau_{1}= \{ U \in X \mid 0 \not\in U \text{ or } U = \Bbb R\} $ and
$ \tau_{2} = \{ U \in X \mid 0 \in U \text{ or } U= \varnothing\}$.

Now define another topology  $\tau_{3}: = \tau_{1} \cap \tau_{2} $.

What is the closure of the set $\{1\}$ in $ \tau_{3} $?

---

**My attempt**

---

For an open set $ U  \in \tau_{1} $, $ 0\not\in U $ or $ U= \Bbb R$, while for an open set
$ U^{'}  \in \tau_{2}$, we have $ 0 \in U $ or $ U= \varnothing $.
Thus $ \Bbb R $ belongs to both topologies but no other non trivial open set belongs to both of them.

Is $ \tau_{3} = \{ \Bbb R, \varnothing \} $?

Is the closure of
$ \{1\} $ the whole $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Looks good: $\tau_3$ is indeed the trivial topology on $\Bbb R$, and the closure of $\{1\}$ is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have edited. Here X= R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2 = \{\varnothing, \Bbb R\}$: the right to left inclusion is obvious, and for the left to right inclusion (contrapositive): if $\varnothing \neq O \subsetneq \Bbb R$, then if $0 \in O$, then $O \notin \tau_1$, and if $0 \notin O$, then $O \notin \tau_2$, and in either case $O \notin \tau_1 \cap \tau_2$.

And in this indiscrete topology the closure of any non-empty subset is $\Bbb R$ as its the *only* closed superset of a non-empty set.

So your solution is correct. Note that the closure of $\{1\}$ in $\tau_1$ is $\{0,1\}$ and in $\tau_2$ it's $\{1\}$. So these are unrelated to the closure of $\{1\}$ in the intersection topology.